# Detecting highlighted browser find text with JS?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

Just trying to solve a minor annoyance.  Let's say we have some content below a "read more" button:

```
the quick brown fox
-------read more-------
jumps over the lazy dog
```

And a person searches for "over", the browser highlights the text, but you can't see the highlight because the content is hidden.

Is there any way to detect this?

Comment: I guess you could loop through html text and highlights found text and displays it with css.

I'm not sure if there is a browser api for this

Comment: Yeah, it's not a normal text range (at least not in Chrome)